# Fetch objects with its relation source objects

Tags: django

The models:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    desc = models.TextField()

class Bid(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
```

So there may be many bids for one offer.

Is there any way to fetch all offers, with its bids without performing query for each offer ?
There's a table with offer list, and I need to add a "B" flag in every row if there's at least one bid.

I tried with prefetch_related(). This worked fine. I got a "bids" attribute attached (as list) for every offer instance, but it resulted in num_offers queries.

```
offers = Offer.objects.prefetch_related(
models.Prefetch('bid_set', to_attr='bids', queryset=Bid.objects.select_related()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are querying from the Offer Model which is 1 to many, then the only available way is to actuallty perform 2 queries (1 for the Offer and 1 for all related bids)

```
offers = Offer.objects.prefetch_related('bid_set').annotate(number_of_bids=models.Count('bid_set')).all()
```

On the other hand, you can create a query from the other side, from the Bid towards the Offer, that would create a singe query with a JOIN:

```
bids = Bid.objects.select_related('offer').all()
offers = [o.offer for o in bids]
```

Which one you prefer depends on what you want and how your data is structured or how many entries your DB contains.

Annotate will produce a virtual number_of_bids field containing the number of bids for each offer.

Comment: **offers = Offer.objects.prefetch_related('bid_set').annotate(number_of_bids=models.Count('bid'))** This one worked. The second solution is not good for my pagination, which works on QuerySets. Thanks

Comment: Forgot the all, does it query multiple times even with all? If yes, can you provide the exact code you are using?

Comment: No. It runs 2 queries like you said. The difference was in Count() argument (bid instead of bid_set) :-)